# Transfer App ID to new Xcode Project

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, cordova

I am updating a Cordova/PhoneGap app that was created over a year ago. The original version was very buggy so rather than fix everything I decided to create a new project and start over. Now that the app is ready to test on a device I am finding it difficult to register the app on iOS Developer.

Would anyone know how to 'transplant' the identity of one app to another Xcode project?

Or are there any good online resources?

Comment: Use same appID and bundelID which you have used for previous application.

Comment: @CRDave can you extrapolate a bit more?

Comment: What problem you are facing in register?

Comment: @CRDave Im not that far yet - I just want to test on a device. Currently the device I used to test the old app on does not appear in the list of testing devices